# How to fetch Data From Same Key in Parse iOS?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

i am newbie in to Parse.com i try to Fetch data from Parse table with same key but value is Different like as

```
-(void)getdata
{
NSMutableArray *allObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
NSUInteger limit = 1000;
__block NSUInteger skip = 0;
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MapInfo"];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MapInfo"];
[query whereKey:@"Type" containedIn:@[@"Temopary", @"Business"]];
[query setLimit: limit];
[query setSkip: skip];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)      {
    if (!error) {
        [allObjects addObjectsFromArray:objects];
        if (objects.count == limit) {

            skip += limit;
            [query setSkip: skip];
            [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                [allObjects addObjectsFromArray:objects];
                self.lqpinname=[allObjects valueForKey:@"GPIN"];
                NSLog(@"Qpin name COunt %@",self.lqpinname);
                self.locationArray=[allObjects valueForKey:@"Location"];
                self.llatitude=[self.locationArray valueForKey:@"lat"];
                self.llongitude=[self.locationArray valueForKey:@"lng"];
                self.laddress=[allObjects valueForKey:@"Address"];
                self.lusernameArray=[allObjects valueForKey:@"AddedBy"];
                hudView.hidden=TRUE;
            }];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
}
```

But it is return `Null` value here i want to Fetch data from table where column `Type=Business & Temporary` Please Give me Solution for this.

thanks.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Please check if you are referring right table or any spell mistake or you are using right app key and etc... I mean to say besides code check everything else for problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `whereKey:containedIn:` to do this.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MapInfo"];
[query whereKey:@"Type" containedIn:@[@"Temopary", @"Business"]];
```

You also have a typo in Temporary (unless Temporay is something) - not sure if that's intentional or not.

Comment: it is Not Working show my updated Question i write code as you say but it is not return any value. and here @"Temopary" and @"Business" is not an array it is only string.